how to build a DSL similar to GINQ?
I'm trying to make a DSL similar to GINQ but superlight, I have to work with groovy 3, so I'm trying that, for the moment there are no plans to migrate to groovy 4, and I find interesting this GINQ DLS.
I'm studying the ATS and deepening with closures, but there is something that I don't know how GINQ does it, and I haven't got it and that is to be able to use aliases in the DLS without the compiler or the IDE marking it as an error, example:
@GQ
def test(){

form x in [1,2,3,4]
select x

}

With GINQ in Groovy 4 this doesn't fail. This is something that I have:
@CompileStatic
class GQueryCodeVisitor extends CodeVisitorSupport{

    @Override
    void visitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression call) {
        if (call.getMethodAsString() == 'select') {
            MethodCallExpression printlnCall = new MethodCallExpression(
                    new VariableExpression("this"),
                    "println",
                    call.getArguments()
            )
            call.setObjectExpression(printlnCall.getObjectExpression())
            call.setMethod(printlnCall.getMethod())
            call.setArguments(printlnCall.getArguments())
        }
        super.visitMethodCallExpression(call)
    }
}

This is something I've been testing, to simulate the select function, when I put
select 'x' //Ouput: x

It works correctly, but when I place
select x 

where x is an undefined variable and I want it to work as an alias, it doesn't work. It fails with this:
The apparent variable 'x' was found in a static scope but does not reference a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:

You tried to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.

You misspelled a class name or a statically imported field. Check the spelling.

You tried to use an 'x' method but omitted parentheses in a place not allowed by the grammar.

@ line 7, column 16.

from x

What I want is to have a DLS similar to linq but in Groovy 3.
